# Inconsistent Webpack with Babel output in using a barrel file between dev and prod

Tags: webpack, babeljs, next.js

I have a project that I transpile using Babel and bundled using Webpack. I found that I get this inconsistent output between dev and prod.

Some context: I'm using decorator for TypeORM and typehint in class parameter for Dependency Injection.

And here is the inconsistency I'm seeing:
Dev:

```
_dec1 = Reflect.metadata(\"design:type\", typeof ___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[\"User\"] === \"undefined\" ? Object : ___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[\"User\"])
```

Prod:

```
_dec1 = Reflect.metadata("design:type", typeof User === "undefined" ? Object : User)
```

This inconsistency caused an issue, the built prod file caused an issue when there is a circular dependency. i.e: Using `User` class before it is defined. Whereas the dev one will not have the issue because it's checking the `User` type through an object (This is achieved by using a barrel file; re-exporting values through an index file). My question is whether I can achieve the same output between dev and prod Webpack (Referring the class through an Object and access the class by a key)

Here is my babel configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have a minimal reproducible repo here: https://github.com/kelvien/repro-next-circ-metadata
Dev file is produced by `npm run dev` and prod is produced by `npm run build`